# Swift : Change the color of a specific X-Axis label and the corresponding data value in a line chart using Charts framework

Tags: ios, swift3, linechart, ios-charts

I am fairly new to Charts framework. I am implementing a line chart using Charts framework and in it I have a requirement to change the color of a specific X Axis label and its corresponding data value. In the chart attached below, the color of X Axis label 2004 and it's coresponding value 3.0 are to be set to different color. Can anyone suggest as to how to achieve this ?[Sample Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrLiO.png)

Comment: Hey, how were you able to add the years on the x axis? I wasnt able to find which method to use. Every reference on the internet mentions "xVals" but that seems to be deprecated for swift 3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the valueColors property of lineChartDataSet. This takes in an array, so you would create a custom function that returns a UIColor.

See the code below:

```
var valueColors = [UIColor]()
var dataEntries = [ChartDataEntry]()
for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
{
    let dataEntry = lineChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    valueColors.append(colorPicker(values[i]))

}

let lineChartDataSet = lineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "")
lineChartDataSet.valueColors = valueColors


func colorPicker(value : Double) -> UIColor {

//input your own logic for how you actually want to color the x axis
    if value == 3 {
        return UIColor.red
    }
    else {
        return UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for.